# Draw function in matlab

Tags: matlab, function

I need to transform my raw input, into function

```
dt = 0.01; 
t1 = 0:dt:1;
t2 = 1+dt:dt:2.5;
t3 = 2.5+dt:dt:3.5;
t4 = 3.5+dt:dt:4;
t5 = 4+dt:dt:4.5;

y1 = ones(size(t1))*-1; 
y2 = 2*(t2-2.5);
y3 = 1*sin(2*pi*(t3-1));
y4 = ones(size(t4))*0;
y5 = rand( size(t5) )-0.5;;

plot(t1, y1, t2, y2, t3, y3, t4, y4, t5 ,y5)
```

"This one works fine ^^^^."

Here i have done it, but something is wrong in the script.

Where did i made mistake?

**How its looks now**

```
function [t1, y1, t2, y2, t3, y3, t4, y4, t5 ,y5]=funct(t)
t = 0.01; % Its every step (0<=t) = (0<=0.01)


t1 =t((0<=t)&(t<1));
y1 = ones(size(t1))*-1;


t2 =t((1<=t)&(t<2.5));
y2 = 2*(t2-2.5);


t3 = t((2.5<=t)&(t<3.5));
y3 = 1*sin(2*pi*(t3-1)); %you wrote sn here


t4 =t((3.5<=t)&(t<4));
y4 = ones(size(t4))*0;


t5=t((4<=t)&(t<4.5));
y5 = rand( size(t5) )-0.5;


plot(t1, y1, t2, y2, t3, y3, t4, y4, t5 ,y5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I obtain the same result.
First I run your code:

```
dt = 0.01; 
t1 = 0:dt:1;
t2 = 1+dt:dt:2.5;
t3 = 2.5+dt:dt:3.5;
t4 = 3.5+dt:dt:4;
t5 = 4+dt:dt:4.5;

y1 = ones(size(t1))*-1; 
y2 = 2*(t2-2.5);
y3 = 1*sin(2*pi*(t3-1));
y4 = ones(size(t4))*0;
y5 = rand( size(t5) )-0.5;;

plot(t1, y1, t2, y2, t3, y3, t4, y4, t5 ,y5)
```

and obtained this:
[image]

After I tried to run your function:

```
t = 0:dt:5;
funct(t)
```

[image]

where

```
function y=funct(t)
%dt = 0.01; %this is not necessary I think

%t1 = 0:dt:1;
t1 =t((0<=t)&(t<1));
y1 = ones(size(t1))*-1;

%t2 = 1+dt:dt:2.5;
t2 =t((1<=t)&(t<2.5));
y2 = 2*(t2-2.5);

%t3 = 2.5+dt:dt:3.5;
t3 = t((2.5<=t)&(t<3.5));
y3 = 1*sin(2*pi*(t3-1)); %you wrote sn here

%t4 = 3.5+dt:dt:4;
t4 =t((3.5<=t)&(t<4));
y4 = ones(size(t4))*0;

%t5 = 4+dt:dt:4.5;
t5=t((4<=t)&(t<4.5));
y5 = rand( size(t5) )-0.5;

y=[y1 y2 y3 y4 y5];

figure
plot(t1, y1, t2, y2, t3, y3, t4, y4, t5 ,y5)
```

I just corrected sn->sin in your code. 
Also not that if you tried to execute `plot(t1, y1, t2, y2, t3, y3, t4, y4, t5 ,y5)` outside the function it cannot work because the function as it is doesn't have enough outputs.

You should modify the first line in the following way:

```
function [t1, y1, t2, y2, t3, y3, t4, y4, t5 ,y5]=funct(t)
```

Hope this helps. Were the errors different?

Comment: Right now its works but , every time i plot its gives me empty graph,  i eddited my code in my main post ^^^.

Comment: **About inputs , dt = 0.01 should be  t = 0.01 , i fixed it and now there are enough inputs **

Comment: @DasHas try to define `t=0:dt:5` not `1`.

Comment: you mean swap  this t1 =t((0<=t)&(t<1));  for this one t1 =t((0<=t)&(t<5));
Its not working

Comment: I do not get this in your code: `t = 0.01; % Its every step (0<=t) = (0<=0.01)
`. In this way you just have one point. So maybe the graph looks empty but its not?

Comment: i simply replace 0.01 with t , otherwise i had to write everywhere 0.01. But my main idea is that i want to make it as function my be there is the simple way to do it?